# Handle business error in api request

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have some api that returns responses in the format

```
{
  code: 0, // 0 is Ok, all other values is error
  data: [{...}, {...}, {...}, ...], // data objects
  message: "" // empty when ok or some error message in other cases
}
```

I try to create communication service for this api

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

interface IApiResponse<T> {
  code: number;
  data: Array<T>;
  message: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

  constructor( 
    private http: Http 
  ) { }

  apiGet<T>(url: string): Observable<Array<T>> {
    return this.http.get(url)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            //.map((api: IApiResponse<T>) => api.code === 0 ? api.data : Observable.throw(api.message))
            .mergeMap((api: IApiResponse<T>) => api.code === 0 ? api.data : Observable.throw(api.message))
            .catch(err => Observable.throw(err));
  }

}
```

I would like to raise exception when code field is not equal 0 and return message in error part of subscribe.
But when i return Observable.throw in map it returns as data in subscribe not as error. 
When i try mergeMap instead, exception returns as error in subscribe  function as expected but data returns for each object in data array. It's not properly for me.
May be i must use some other observable function for this?

Service usage in a component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

interface ITestItem {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.apiGet<ITestItem>('/api/test')
      .subscribe(
        // only data when code = 0 or nothing
        data => console.log("data section:", data), 
        // handle http errors and message when code != 0
        error => console.log("error section:", error), 
        () => console.log("api request completed")
      );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this happens is because mergeMap will convert the result to an Observable if it is possible. Since your data is an array it converts it to an Observable and emits each element contained.

Wrap your data with `Rx.Observable.of()` in the `.mergeMap` to keep it as an Array emission

Comment: Yes, it works! But i can't understand why Observable.throw works in map and mergeMap differently.

Comment: The map function does not cast the results to Observable so when your map function returns an Observable.throw that will be the value it emits to the `next` function of subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close, based on the [RxJS doc](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/throw.md). You need to throw an exception like so:

```
 Observable.throw(new Error(api.message));
```

Hope that helps

**EDIT more info**

Service, make whatever change neccessary for your need.

```
getTestData(): any {
    return this.http.get("testUrlShouldThrowError")
      .map((api: any) => {
        if (api.code === 0) {
          return <IApiResponse<Test>>api.data
        }
        else {
          return Observable.throw(new Error("Error!"))
        }
      });
  }
```

Subscription:

```
this.testService.getTestData().subscribe(
      data => console.log(data.error.message),
    )
```

Comment: .map((api: IApiResponse<T>) => api.code === 0 ? api.data : Observable.throw(new Error(api.message))) returns ErrorObservable in data part of subscribe.

Comment: @avvensis Yes, but you can access your error message in your subscribe  `error => console.log("error section:", error.error.message)`

Comment: What shall i do for it?

Comment: I repeated your code and get output in console: data section: ErrorObservable... console.log(data.error.message) doen't work because TypeScript expects ITestItem in data and it doesn't have error property. So i should check data type it's array of interface or ErrorObservable each time in every component. It's not good idea for me.

Comment: Noticed... 3 lines... `getTestData(): any` returns any, `.map((api: any)` also type of any... IF SUCCESS `return <IApiResponse<Test>>api.data` cast it to Type of Test in your case ITestItem.

Comment: You're right. But i would like to gap data and errors in subscription and get situation like this: subscribe(data => only data, error => only errors). It's much more easy return complete json object and check code === 0 in subscribe each time. Your decision is same. Also using a lot of any in TypeScript it's a bit crazy :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134212/discussion-between-avvensis-and-12seconds).